# How to upload file using loopback api explorer?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using loopback Api Explorer I need to upload a file by explore how can I upload that because I don't find any option to upload file please refer the screenshot

[image].

Comment: Have you looked into the Loopback Storage component? https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Storage+component

Comment: If your on Mac you can also git Paw a go https://paw.cloud/ see the documenation on file upload/multipart body https://paw.cloud/docs/getting-started/set-request-body#Set_Multipart_body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, the answer is that you can't. Uploading a file requires multi-part form data. This isn't currently possible via the loopback-component-explorer. You should checkout the [loobpack-component-storage](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage) instead. There is an [example here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-storage); I recommend using the `example-2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with something like [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/).

But, the only that you need, is the path of the file, not the file.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than using Postman would be using curl direct on the terminal :

Here is the command I use when need(I work with some services using loopback/explorer as well) :

`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "blob=@/path/to/your/file.jpg" -v http://HOST:PORT/pathToYourEndpoint?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx`